# Create history map with inkscape with each country as a distinct object

Tags: cartography, history, inkscape, tesselation

I want to create history maps (maps showing historical borders) with inkscape and to have an object for each country.

I want to draw borders between countries only once and have this part of a path duplicated and assigned to the bordering countries.

E.g. I want to draw the border between France and Spain only once and have it assigned to both countries.

I know that I can simply draw each border as a separate path, cut out a part or use the whole path, copy it and merge each copy with the rest of the respective country's outline.

Is there a better approach to the problem?

Is there a tool, e.g. an Inkscape addon, that can identify all path part combinations that surround and therefore define areas?

Answer (score 5):

Using QGIS and Inkscape

In QGIS load up a country (France Example here)

Classify the provinces (by name) set with random colours

Use the QGIS composer to set up the export to SVG.

In Inkscape
Copy and paste (in place) into new layer for the provinces repeat (or automate/batch) to make the polygons all separate.

[image]

Then style based on your map design/theme.

Comment: how to handle the shared boundary though? Otherwise... yes... inkscape + QGIS is great!!!

Comment: you can union the polygons  and export to paths to get the shared boundary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, +1. Unfortunately, my question wasn't clearly asked. I want to create history maps showing historical borders - see modified question.